# WPF CheckBox in ComboBox DataTemplate does not work in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a `ComboBox` that includes a `CheckBox` by changing the `DataTemplate`, this works fine when done on its own, but when moving it into a `DataGrid` the `CheckBox` is not clickable.

Working Code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding WrapUpHelper.WrapUps}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                          Width="20" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyDescription}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding WrapUps}"
                                     Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     Background="Transparent">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                      Width="20" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyDescription}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

Proof:

[image]

But when adding this same logic to a `DataGrid`, instead of adding the checkmark to the `CheckBox`, the `ComboBox` closes with nothing selected.

Non working code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Wrap up" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding WrapUpHelper.WrapUps}">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                          Width="20" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyDescription}" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding WrapUps}"
                                                     Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                                      Background="Transparent">
                                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Width="20" />
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FriendlyDescription}" />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ListBox>

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any event through on them? Might try adding `ClickMode="Press"` to the CB's

Comment: @ChrisW. Please change this to answer and I can mark it correct, this allows the `CheckBoxes` to be ticked within a `DataGrid`, now the only issue is on every click the `ComboBox` closes.

Comment: Alrighty, PS for the second part I always did something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667203/expand-the-combobox-and-its-items-when-it-gets-focus). :)

Comment: @ChrisW. thank you, I went for another solution as the space felt a bit cramped in the `DataGrid` after I was asked to add more functionality in the `ComboBox`. But this seems like a simple solution to anyone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a nested control whose parent would normally hijack HitTestVisibility you can bubble out and allow the nested control to respond to it's normal events in lieu of it's parent by using [ClickMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.clickmode(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration via the property of `ClickMode="Pressed"` being added to the control in question.

Hope this helps, cheers!